# MS Project VBA updating Groups - show in menu

Tags: vba, ms-project

MS Project VBA.  I would like to change a Group definition (Project, Group By in MS Project) in VBA but can’t find a way to change one that is already there (I can add more groups to it, but can’t delete  the first grouping).  What I have done is delete the group definition that is there and then define the one I want, but then I can’t find a way to show that in the menu. 
This is the code I have for deleting the Group definition, then defining a new one
        ActiveProject.TaskGroups.item("CSR - CA").Delete
        ActiveProject.TaskGroups.Add "CSR - CA", CSRField
        ActiveProject.TaskGroups("CSR - CA").GroupCriteria.Add CAWBSField
        ActiveProject.TaskGroups("CSR - CA").GroupCriteria.Add CCNField

Can you help me to find a way to change the Group so that it is shown in the menu please?